# Can I make the front-end entry form send an email to a user group?

Tags: emails, entry-form

I've used the front-end entry form in the docs to build a Q&A portal, and it's working great. But I'd like to extend the functionality once the new entry is saved.

I've set the entries up to not be enabled when saved so that a moderation team can later approve them. Is there a way for members of the moderator user group to receive an email every time someone publishes a new question via the front-end form?

Comment: Are you posting these front-end entries to a custom plugin controller's action or are you going straight through Craft's `entries/saveEntry`?

Comment: I'm going through `entries/saveEntry`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple [plugin](http://pluginfactory.io) that listens for the [onSaveEntry](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onSaveEntry) event.

When that event fires, you plugin could check the `$isNewEntry` param to make sure it's a new entry being saved and also check the entry's section to make sure it's the front-end section you're expecting and might as well check `craft()->request->isSiteRequest()` to make sure it's a front-end request.

If all of those match, you would get the users in a group, then loop through all of them sending an email with [`craft()->email->sendEmail()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EmailService#sendEmail-detail) for each user.

Something like (pseudocode):

```
$element = craft()->elements->getElementType(ElementType::Users);
$element->group = 'groupHandle';
$users = $element->find();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
    // compose email body, header, etc.
    $success = craft()->email->sendEmail($email, $variables);
}
```